# Are there non-simple Jordan algebra that do not have nilpotent elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, jordan-algebras

Clearly if a Jordan algebra has nilpotent element, the algebra is non-simple.

I suppose the converse is not true and there are non-simple Jordan algebras without nilpotent elements, but there might be a theorem that I'm missing. In particular I'm working with infinite dimensional algebras (so a nilpotent element do not guarantee the existence of a maximal idempotent element, if that's needed).

Could you please tell me if that is the case?  Sorry if this question is trivial, but really is not my expertise.

Comment: I may have an ad-hoc example. Over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ consider the algebra $A$ generated by $\{a,b\}$ and non-zero products given by: $a^2=a,b^2=b$. Notice that $x^2-x=0$ is satisfied for any $x\in A$. In this case the jordan identity follows from commutativity since $x^2(yx)-(x^2y)x=x(yx)-(xy)x$. Because every element is idempotent, there are no nilpotent other than zero, moreover $\langle a \rangle=\{ta:t\in \mathbb{Z}_2\}$ is a non trivial ideal. You can extend this example to an infinite dimensional quite easily but I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.

Comment: That's a great comment! How do you proof in an infinite case that has not nilpotent elements? Could you write it as answer so that I can give you some points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a set of indexes $I$ (possibly uncountable) and consider $B=\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$. Consider the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ algebra $A$ with basis $B$ and non-zero products given by $a_i^2=a_i$. We can write $x\in A$ as a linear combination of say $a_{i_1},...,a_{i_k}$ and $y\in A$ as a combination of $a_{j_1},...,a_{j_l}$, either way we consider both $x$ and $y$ as a combination of $a_{i_1},...,a_{i_k},a_{j_1},...,a_{j_l}$ by adding a zero as a coefficient in case some element does not appear in the expression and label them as $a_1,...,a_p$ (this will simplify the notation).

From that we have $(\sum_{r=1}^p x_{r}a_{r})(\sum_{s=1}^p y_{s}a_{s})=\sum\sum x_{r}y_{s}a_{r}a_{s}=\sum x_{r}y_{r}a_{r}^2$. In particular, if $x=y$ it follows that $x^2=x$. Therefore the only nilpotent element is $0$.

The vectos space $\langle a_1\rangle$ is also an ideal for $(\sum_{r=1}^p x_{r}a_{r})a_1=\delta_{1,x}a_1$ where $\delta_{1,x}=0$ if $a_1$ does not appear in the expression of $x$ and $\delta_{1,x}=x_1$, the coefficient of $a_1$ in the expression of $x$. Either way it belongs to the space generated by $a_1$. Since $A$ is commutative, it is an ideal. The Jordan identity is immediate.